# How to a read user Information from Firebase database and display as a List in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new here and I'd be glad if anyone can help me.What I want to do is get UID and Username of all the users and display it in a list.

Here is my related code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for(DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    **// Not sure what to do here**

                    array.add(username);
                   }

              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);
               }
```

My Users `Class` which I use to Insert User Information

```
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String phone;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String phone) {
        this.username = username;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }


}
```

And this is how my Database Looks like
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2rdx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String phone = ds.child("phone").getVelue(String.class);
            String username = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", phone + " / " + username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And your uotput will be:

```
uo / pol
809151699 / shivam
//and so on
```

Hope it helps.